# RabbitMQ: Is message duplicated when routed from RabbitMq exchange to each queue

Tags: rabbitmq

In RabbitMQ, If I have an exchange and two queues bound to it with same routing key for example "rk1*", how many copies of the message will be physically stored in Rabbit?

More generally, does Rabbit store separate copy of message for each queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I inspected the file system and I found that message is copied, at least on disk, for every queue.

I've created Durable Topic exchange and 2 queues bound to it with same routing key.

This is how directory structure looks like:
[image]

When I publish message to the exchange, I can see it's text in the .idx file for each queue:
[image]

So I guess this answers my question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what kind of exchange you have? Do you have a direct exchange, a topic exchange, or a fanout exchange.

[Here](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-05-18-part1-rabbitmq-for-beginners-what-is-rabbitmq.html) is more on RabbitMq architecture.

[Here](https://codedestine.com/rabbitmq-fanout-exchange/) is some working demo code for setting up a fanout exchange.

Comment: @Eduard Grinberg it my answer was what you were looking for, request you to leave an upvote and accept it as a solution. Cheers.